# CQL copy to Cassandra table does not work

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a tsv file, with records like these:

```
"county_id" "county_desc"   "voter_reg_num" "status_cd" "voter_status_desc" "reason_cd" "voter_status_reason_desc"  "absent_ind"    "name_prefx_cd" "last_name" "first_name"    "middle_name"   "name_suffix_lbl"   "res_street_address"    "res_city_desc" "state_cd"  "zip_code"  "mail_addr1"    "mail_addr2"    "mail_addr3"    "mail_addr4"    "mail_city" "mail_state"    "mail_zipcode"  "full_phone_number" "race_code" "ethnic_code"   "party_cd"  "gender_code"   "birth_age" "birth_state"   "drivers_lic"   "registr_dt"    "precinct_abbrv"    "precinct_desc" "municipality_abbrv"    "municipality_desc" "ward_abbrv"    "ward_desc" "cong_dist_abbrv"   "super_court_abbrv" "judic_dist_abbrv"  "nc_senate_abbrv"   "nc_house_abbrv"    "county_commiss_abbrv"  "county_commiss_desc"   "township_abbrv"    "township_desc" "school_dist_abbrv" "school_dist_desc"  "fire_dist_abbrv"   "fire_dist_desc"    "water_dist_abbrv"  "water_dist_desc"   "sewer_dist_abbrv"  "sewer_dist_desc"   "sanit_dist_abbrv"  "sanit_dist_desc"   "rescue_dist_abbrv" "rescue_dist_desc"  "munic_dist_abbrv"  "munic_dist_desc"   "dist_1_abbrv"  "dist_1_desc"   "dist_2_abbrv"  "dist_2_desc"   "confidential_ind"  "age"   "ncid"  "vtd_abbrv" "vtd_desc"
"1" "ALAMANCE"  "000009005990"  "A" "ACTIVE"    "AV"    "VERIFIED"  " " " " "AABEL" "EVELYN"    "LARSEN"    ""  "4430 E GREENSBORO-CHAPEL HILL RD   "   "GRAHAM"    "NC"    "27253" "4430 E GREENSBORO-CHAPEL HILL RD"  ""  ""  ""  "GRAHAM"    "NC"    "27253" "0000000"   "W" "NL"    "UNA"   "F" "80"    "NY"    "N" "10/01/1984"    "08N"   "NORTH NEWLIN"  ""  ""  ""  ""  "06"    "15A"   "15A"   "24"    "064"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "15A"   "15A PROSECUTORIAL" " " " " "N" "Age Over 66"   "AA56273"   "08N"   "08N"
"1" "ALAMANCE"  "000009048723"  "A" "ACTIVE"    "AV"    "VERIFIED"  " " " " "AARON" "CHRISTINA" "CASTAGNA"  ""  "421  WHITT AVE   " "BURLINGTON"    "NC"    "27215" "421 WHITT AVE" ""  ""  ""  "BURLINGTON"    "NC"    "27215" "3362291110"    "W" "UN"    "UNA"   "F" "40"    "NC"    "Y" "03/26/1996"    "03S"   "SOUTH BOONE"   "BUR"   "BURLINGTON"    ""  ""  "06"    "15A"   "15A"   "24"    "064"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "BUR"   "BURLINGTON"    "15A"   "15A PROSECUTORIAL" " " " " "N" "Age 26 - 40"   "AA98377"   "03S"   "03S"
"1" "ALAMANCE"  "000009019674"  "A" "ACTIVE"    "AV"    "VERIFIED"  " " " " "AARON" "CLAUDIA"   "HAYDEN"    ""  "1013  EDITH ST   " "BURLINGTON"    "NC"    "27215" "1013 EDITH ST" ""  ""  ""  "BURLINGTON"    "NC"    "27215" "2228834"   "W" "NL"    "UNA"   "F" "71"    "VA"    "Y" "08/15/1989"    "124"   "BURLINGTON 4"  "BUR"   "BURLINGTON"    ""  ""  "06"    "15A"   "15A"   "24"    "063"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "BUR"   "BURLINGTON"    "15A"   "15A PROSECUTORIAL" " " " " "N" "Age Over 66"   "AA69747"   "124"   "124"
"1" "ALAMANCE"  "000009129589"  "A" "ACTIVE"    "AV"    "VERIFIED"  " " " " "AARON" "JAMES" "MICHAEL"   ""  "5608  OLD CHEROKEE LN   "  "GRAHAM"    "NC"    "27253" "PO BOX 98" ""  ""  ""  "SAXAPAHAW" "NC"    "27340" "2027443411"    "W" "UN"    "DEM"   "M" "68"    "MA"    "N" "03/07/2012"    "08N"   "NORTH NEWLIN"  ""  ""  ""  ""  "06"    "15A"   "15A"   "24"    "064"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "15A"   "15A PROSECUTORIAL" " " " " "N" "Age Over 66"   "AA170513"  "08N"   "08N"
```

And this schema :

```
create keyspace test with replication  = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor' : 1 };
create table voters(
county_id           varchar,    
county_desc         varchar ,
voter_reg_num       varchar ,
status_cd           varchar ,
voter_status_desc   varchar ,
reason_cd           varchar ,
voter_status_reason_desc    varchar ,
absent_ind          varchar ,
name_prefx_cd       varchar ,
last_name           varchar ,
first_name          varchar ,
midl_name           varchar ,
name_sufx_cd        varchar,
res_street_address  varchar ,
res_city_desc       varchar ,
state_cd            varchar,
zip_code            varchar,
mail_addr1          varchar ,
mail_addr2          varchar ,
mail_addr3          varchar ,
mail_addr4          varchar ,
mail_city           varchar ,
mail_state          varchar,
mail_zipcode        varchar,
full_phone_number   varchar,
race_code           varchar,
ethnic_code         varchar,
party_cd            varchar,
gender_code         varchar,
birth_age           varchar     ,  
birth_place         varchar,
drivers_lic         varchar ,       
registr_dt          varchar,
precinct_abbrv      varchar,
precinct_desc       varchar,
municipality_abbrv  varchar,
municipality_desc   varchar ,
ward_abbrv          varchar,
ward_desc           varchar ,
cong_dist_abbrv     varchar,
super_court_abbrv   varchar,
judic_dist_abbrv    varchar,
nc_senate_abbrv     varchar,
nc_house_abbrv      varchar,
county_commiss_abbrv varchar,
county_commiss_desc     varchar,    
township_abbrv       varchar,
township_desc        varchar,   
school_dist_abbrv    varchar,   
school_dist_desc     varchar,   
fire_dist_abbrv      varchar,   
fire_dist_desc       varchar,   
water_dist_abbrv     varchar,   
water_dist_desc      varchar,   
sewer_dist_abbrv     varchar,   
sewer_dist_desc      varchar,   
sanit_dist_abbrv     varchar,   
sanit_dist_desc      varchar,   
rescue_dist_abbrv    varchar,   
rescue_dist_desc     varchar,   
munic_dist_abbrv     varchar,
munic_dist_desc      varchar,   
dist_1_abbrv         varchar,   
dist_1_desc          varchar,   
dist_2_abbrv         varchar,
dist_2_desc          varchar,   
Confidential_ind     varchar,   
age                 varchar      ,   
ncid                    varchar,     
vtd_abbrv           varchar     ,
vtd_desc            varchar     ,
primary key(voter_reg_num)
);
```

When I try to copy to a cassandra table, with :

```
COPY voters FROM 'sample.tsv' WITH DELIMITER='\t';
```

I get:

```
Processed: 1000 rows; Rate:    1230 rows/s; Avg. rate:    1945 rows/s
1000 rows imported from 1 files in 0.514 seconds (0 skipped).
```

However, when I do a count I realize that only one record has been copied to the table.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your schema ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I updated the question with the schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add Column name with copy command**

```
COPY voters(county_id,county_desc,voter_reg_num,status_cd,voter_status_desc,reason_cd,voter_status_reason_desc,absent_ind,name_prefx_cd,last_name,first_name,middle_name,name_suffix_lbl,res_street_address,res_city_desc,state_cd,zip_code,mail_addr1,mail_addr2,mail_addr3,mail_addr4,mail_city,mail_state,mail_zipcode,full_phone_number,race_code,ethnic_code,party_cd,gender_code,birth_age,birth_state,drivers_lic,registr_dt,precinct_abbrv,precinct_desc,municipality_abbrv,municipality_desc,ward_abbrv,ward_desc,cong_dist_abbrv,super_court_abbrv,judic_dist_abbrv,nc_senate_abbrv,nc_house_abbrv,county_commiss_abbrv,county_commiss_desc,township_abbrv,township_desc,school_dist_abbrv,school_dist_desc,fire_dist_abbrv,fire_dist_desc,water_dist_abbrv,water_dist_desc,sewer_dist_abbrv,sewer_dist_desc,sanit_dist_abbrv,sanit_dist_desc,rescue_dist_abbrv,rescue_dist_desc,munic_dist_abbrv,munic_dist_desc,dist_1_abbrv,dist_1_desc,dist_2_abbrv,dist_2_desc,confidential_ind,age,ncid,vtd_abbrv,vtd_desc) FROM 'sample.tsv' WITH DELIMITER='\t' AND HEADER = true;
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me, I still have the following errors `Failed to import x rows: ParseError - Invalid row length y should be z,  given up without retries`. However I used the command line you gave

Comment: @Marine1 same data ?

Answer (score 0):

If your tsv file has the columns names at the top, then don't forget to add WITH HEADER = TRUE to your COPY command. I would also remove the double quotes and verify that the fields are separated by tabs and not spaces. To test just create a new tsv file with 50 lines or so from the original and make your changes there. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I forgot to write the header=true condition. I created a file with 50 lines and removed the double quotes like you said, but now I have another problem. Some fields that are null disappeared, then I got this:                 Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 70 should be 71,  given up without retries
Failed to import 4 rows: ParseError - Invalid row length 69 should be 71,  given up without retries
Failed to process 5 rows; failed rows written to import_test_voters.err

Comment: If you change to | or comma delimited and remove the quotes does the error persist? I'm not sure how much control you have over how the TSV files are generated so that may not be a practical approach. It looks like the columns in your header and table are in order. One scenario where only a single row gets imported is where the primary key is the same across the board, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.